# Document is not getting saved in Sharepoint using Firefox browser

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I have a document stored in SharePoint, and when I try to edit the document through Internet explorer the document get edited and the new document gets saved in SharePoint, whereas when I try to open the same document in Firefox and try to edit, the document is telling to save the document in my local computer and its get saved in local computer. If i need that document again in SharePoint the only way is to upload the document again. But this is not what I want, I want to edit the document directly in SharePoint and get saved. Which is happening in Internet explorer but not in Firefox

Anybody had issue in the past and if there is a solution of what changes should I do in Firefox so that I can edit the document directly in SharePoint through Firefox

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that kind of integration is available in Firefox. Does it work with IE?

Comment: Yes, it works on IE and also on Firefox for some users. But for some users it does not work on Firefox. But no issues or complain about IE as of now. I personally tried in my IE and Firefox and it worked for me. But one of the users I tried it worked in IE but not or Firefox.Not sure why?

Comment: SharePoint uses ActiveX controls extensively, especially for Office integration. IE comes with ActiveX built in. Other browsers don't. Firefox has a plug in for that.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox requires the "Microsoft Office" plugin to work with SharePoint. When you try to Edit the item for the first time, Firefox asks you that your server wants to install this plugin. Choose to install and remember and you will be able to enjoy Firefox to SharePoint integration.

Regards